# In '<string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python

How can I make Python quit if a list contains a particular word?

```
text = input("Input text: ")
if["exit","quit","close"] in text:
    Quit()
```

Comment: your if statement is the wrong way round, `text in [...]`

Answer (score 3):

It's the other way around

```
if text in ["exit","quit","close"]:
```

You can read it as pseudo English, you are checking if the string is in the list.

If you want to check if part of the input is in the list you can use `any`

```
if any(x in ["exit", "quit", "close"] for x in text.split(' ')):
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards.  Try

> if text in ["...","..."]:

Think of it as "If this is in that".